# not showing admob banner ads using google play service in android

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have developed an application that have integrate google ad-mob ads service using new google play service so when i am implement in my project there some issue of not showing banner ads

my code is here.

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4"></WebView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="*************" />
```

Manifest file

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Comment: Have you included the `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` tag somewhere?

Comment: no i didnt use it anywhere

Comment: Try including it in your `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` view.

Comment: Are you sure your `UnitId` is ok? I removed it but it seemed to be a little bit short...

Comment: yes u mean publisher id..

Comment: it contain alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to put in a request in your code, something like this:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Otherwise it just takes up layout space, but doesn't do anything. Not sure why they forced added code with the Google Play Services version of Admob, but they do, so...

Note that you only need to do this once, after you've added this it will auto-reload them according to your Admob settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you have padding left or right in your parent layout remove it and try again! I had the same problem with you and I just solve it with that trick....you can see following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
        adview.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and in `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: have you cross check your id? it may be problem there